# Getting a javascript function to reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a keyup function which checks the value of how many characters are inputted into a password field. It works for the most part, but if I delete the characters I cannot figure out how to get the image to reset back to its default state.

How can I do this?

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  if (password.length >= 6) {
    $("#characters").addClass('none');
    hasError = true;
  }
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div id="password-check">
    <div class="password-check-field">
      <img id="characters" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at least 6 characters</div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
  <label for="signinButton">
    <input id="signinButton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register">
  </label>
  <br>
</form>
```

uPDATE

```
<div class="password-check-field">
    <img id="characters" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">
    <img id="charactersOK" class="none" src="icons/collection/checkmark.png" alt="Success">
    Your password has at least 6 characters
</div>

$("#charactersOK").addClass("block");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the case when the password length is less than 6 characters and if so remove the `none` class. You can make this logic more succinct by using `toggleClass()`;

Also note that your `hasError` variable seems backwards; surely it should only be `true` when `password < 6`. Try this:

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var passwordLengthValid = $("#password").val().length >= 6;
  $("#characters").toggleClass('none', passwordLengthValid);
  var hasError = !passwordLengthValid;

  // Note that if you want to change image src instead of hide it, use this:
  $('#characters').attr('src', passwordLengthValid ? 'valid-image.jpg' : 'error-image.jpg');
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div id="password-check">
    <div class="password-check-field">
      <img id="characters" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at least 6 characters</div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
  <label for="signinButton">
    <input id="signinButton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register">
  </label>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Very Illuminating.

Comment: Thanks! How could I add a new image in place when it goes over the 6 though? I tried adding `$("#charactersOK").addClass("block");` the class block being `display: block;`. I added code to the bottom with how I changed the field.

Comment: To change the image use `$("#characters").attr('src', 'new-image-file-here.jpg')`

Comment: Adding that, even one character added changed the src.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose code I can't see, but I added a working example for you above.

Comment: Assuming the file paths to those images are correct, that should work fine. Maybe try `/icons/...`

Comment: They are both in the same folder. The Circle with the dash (one that is default) works. Just the other one doesn't (checkmark one) doesn't work.

Comment: The toggle code is what was killing it... `$("#characters").toggleClass('none', passwordLengthValid);` Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Ah yes, I should have stated it was either change class *or* change attr() - not both :) glad to help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am trying to apply this logic to a similar input, but can't figure it out. I created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069274/getting-image-to-change-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found-in-an-input

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (password.length >= 6) {
  $("#characters").addClass('none');
  hasError = true;
} else {
  $("#characters").removeClass('none')
  hasError = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `else`:

```
if(password.length >= 6) {
    $("#characters").addClass('none');
    hasError = true;
} else {
    $("#characters").removeClass('none');
    hasError = false;
}
```

Also, isn't you `hasError` backwards? If there are more than 6 characters, shouldn't there not be an error, so `hasError` should be `false`?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the class if not needed.

```
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  if (password.length >= 6) {
    $("#characters").addClass('none');
    hasError = true;
  } else{
    $("#characters").removeClass('none');
    hasError = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for this:

```
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  hasError = password.length >= 6; // make sure to set the correct error condition here
  $("#characters").toggleClass('none', hasError);
});
```