# Getting image to change when an uppercase letter is found in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to check if there is at least one uppercase letter in the password input and if so, change the default 'delete' image and change it to a checkmark image.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var upperCase = $("#upperCase").val();
  var upperCaseValid = upperCase.toUpperCase().length >= 1;
  /*if (upperCaseValid == upperCaseValid.toUpperCase()) {
   $('#upperCase').attr('src', 'icons/collection/checkmark.png');
  }*/
  $('#upperCase').attr('src', upperCaseValid ? 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlyqJ14HYP1WclpK9RkJWo8jIDBkhTW0GS31AxRkozAEA72ULhY89LIzk' : 'icons/collection/delete.png');
});
```

```css
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="password-check-field">
    <img id="upperCase" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at least 1 capital letter
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a string contains an uppercase character you can use a Regular Expression, specifically `[A-Z]`. Also note that in your example you're checking the value of the `#upperCase` element, which is an image. I think that selector should be `#password` instead. Try this;

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var upperCaseValid = $("#password").val().match(/[A-Z]/g);
  $('#upperCase').attr('src', upperCaseValid ? 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlyqJ14HYP1WclpK9RkJWo8jIDBkhTW0GS31AxRkozAEA72ULhY89LIzk' : 'icons/collection/delete.png');
});
```

```css
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="password-check-field">
    <img id="upperCase" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at least 1 capital letter
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the `toUpperCase` was the only function that did this. What does the g in `.match(/[A-Z]/g);` do?

Comment: Not quite. `toUpperCase()` only converts a string to uppercase characters, it doesn't detect them. The part you highlighted is the regular expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Try use this (I used text instead of images):

```
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var upperCaseValid = /[A-Z]/.test($('#password').val());
  $('#msg').text(upperCaseValid ? 'Password contains uppercase character(s)' : 'Password doesn\'t contain uppercase character(s)');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bz2zLsbs/